# Published app showing different signatures on google play

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, in-app-update, app-update

I have an app on playstore hosted via someone else's account. I made an update via playstore, it went successful. Now i was checking third release by directly installing apk from phone(not from playstore) to overwrite version 2, it failed to install. When i searched on google, i found and verified it is signature issue. Both have different signatures, from my side everything is fine. 
The ultimate problem is output signatures are different from input signatures. How?

Answer (score 3):

Do you use app signing by google play? It may be due to it that the signatures are different.

If you've used app signing then google manages your app's signing key for you and uses it to sign your APKs for distribution on play store. The one you've installed from the APK is signed by your upload key.

Answer (score 0):

You will get that warning if you try to update previously installed app (same package name) with different signature key. You would pass that warning if you first uninstall the app from your device and then install apk again.

The reason it has different signature key is that might be of debug version of apk or an app bundle you are trying to install. (so its signature would be different than the one you installed from play store) Or another possibility is that if you let Google manage your app's signing key for you on Google Play Console, then your released apk's will be signed with a temporary signature key to let you upload on Google Play.